# Associate a php function to a submit button created using Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, visual-composer

I have created a custom form using Visual composer in wordpress with two fields

1) Name
2) Email Address

Now on clicking submit button i want to store these values in session variables. I have created the function for the same. How cn i associate the function with the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your PHP function using wp_ajax action hook on button click.

Reference Link : [How to run ajax on click](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/how-can-i-run-ajax-on-a-button-click-event)